# Finding max returns unexpected output

Tags: python, sorting

I am undertaking a course in discrete mathematics. During this course our book talks about different sorting algorithms. To better understand this I tried to translate one of these algorithms into python, however the algorithm returns some unexpected output and I am failing to realise where my error is. If you would, please have a look below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
### Find max ###
# A = Array of values to find max from.
# n = Length of array A. Can also be described as the number of loops the array will perform

A = [100, 3, 7, 15, 17, 19, 25, 31, 32, 8, 21, 5, 51, 64, 63]
n = len(A) #len: python command to retrieve length of an array.

def find_max(A, n):

    max = 0

    for i in range(0, n):
        if A[i] > max:
            max = i
    return max

### Input A and N in the algorithm and print the output ###
print find_max(A, n)
```

Here the expected output should be 0 since the first entry in the array has the highest value. However the script returns 14, which is the highest key in the array.

I would like the python script to resemble the pseudo code as much as possible. Simply so it is easier for us new students to compare the them to eachother. This is the pseudo code from our book:

```
find_max(A, n)
    max = 0
    for i = 0 to n-1
        if (A[i] > A[max]) max = i
    return max
```

Comment: `if A[i] > max:
            max = A[i]`. Mixing up indices with values.

Comment: you can use `for a in A: if a > max: max = a` to avoid playing with indices. of course built-in `max` function is best in all cases.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you answering. Would you mind to elaborate on your comment? I am not sure what indices refers to in this context.

Comment: (1)Avoid using max as a variable,it's already a built in function. (2) you are assigning max to i instead of A[i]

Comment: I would recommend that you avoid using 0 for your initial value of `max`.  What if your array only contains negative values?  Maybe instead try doing `maxv = A[0]` and then searching for a larger value `for i in range(1,n):`.  Or, another apoach is that you could store the index of the max value: `maxi = 0` and then `if A[i] > A[maxi]: maxi = i`

Comment: @TheChetan 1) I will avoid using max. 2) I would like to function to return the index of the highest value, not the highest value itself. This is what the pseudo code I am replicating does aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `max` as a variable because it's a Python keyword, second, your variable `max` (let's call it `mx`), is holding the index of the maximum value, not the value itself, so here's a solution to your problem :

```
A = [17, 19, 25, 31, 32, 3, 7, 15, 8, 21, 100, 5, 51, 64, 63]
n = len(A)

def find_max(A, n):

    mx = 0 # we call it mx

    for i in range(1, n): # since mx = 0, no need start at 0
        if A[i] > A[mx]: # we compare the number in A[i] with the number in A[mx] not with mx
            mx = i
    return mx # index

print(find_max(A, n)) # => 10
```

Comment: I want the function to return the index of the highest number. Not the number itself.

Comment: @n0rd Just return `mx` instead of `A[mx]` as explained.

Comment: accepting this answer because changing the variable max to mx solves the issue. Also this answer was helpfull in understanding the issue, while maintaning an accurate version of the original code, aswell as staying focused on the specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why it doesn't work: your attempt is mixing indices & values.

to look like the pseudo-code (with, added a check in case the array is empty so it doesn't return 0):

```
def find_max(A, n)
    if not A:
       raise Exception("empty array")

    max = 0
    for i in range(1,n): # no need to start at 0, already covered
        if A[i] > A[max]:
          max = i
    return max
```

As a conclusion, the best way to be efficient and pythonic would probably be to use `enumerate` to carry indices & values and built-in `max` with a lambda to tell `max` to look for the values:

```
max(enumerate(A),key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

Comment: I would like the code to resemble the pseudo code in the book as much as possible. Simply so it is easier to compare the two. I will post the pseudo code above.

Comment: so go for the quickfix.

Comment: The quickfix makes the function return the highest number. I want the function to return the index of the highest number. Not the number itself.

Comment: of course: I fixed your attempt but since you didn't tell anything about returning indices I just assumed that you wanted to return values. Edited.

Comment: On an empty list, I would raise a `ValueError`, rather than `Exception`.  Additionally, I would make `n` an optional value that defaults to `len(A)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You shouldn't use `max` as a variable name, that's also one the reasons the program wasn't working.

Comment: I know i shouldnt but it works though (shadowing). Not recommended though

Answer (score 1):

this would get the job done :

```
def find_max(A, n):

    max = 0

    for i in range(0, n):
        if A[i] > max:
            max = A[i]
return max
```

or you can use the buil-in max function :

```
result = max(A)
```

Comment: in which this answers differs from / improves the already posted answer?

Comment: The original poster is requesting the index of the largest value, not the largest value itself.

Comment: My bad, didn't check very well. But I think the question was updated